# Android AsyncTask: How to handle the return type

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android application that executes an **http POST request**, and the tutorial I followed was resulting in an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

The *original code* was something like this.

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

And this class was invoked with this line.

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
```

After changing this to an AsyncTask class, the code looks like this.

```
class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// variables passed in:
String url;
List<NameValuePair> params;

// constructor
public JSONParser(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    this.url = url;
    this.params = params;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jObj) {
    return;
}       
}
```

My question is, how do I return a `JSONObject` from this new *AsyncTask* class?I can see that `jObj` is being returned in `doInBackground()`, but I am not sure where it is being returned to.

What do I need to modify or how do I need to call my new `JSONParser` class so that it is returning a `JSONObject`?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code, it may give you an insight as to how to deal with the parsing of JSON objects. I am just posting the onPostExecute function for now because you seemed to have all the rest figured correctly.

As for your doubt as to where the data object from the doInBackground is returned, it is automatically sent to the onPostExecute where you can further on parse it.

```
            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
        try
        {   
            JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject("data");
                      // whatever your JSON tag may be, in this case its data.

            if (data.isNull("data"))
            {
                      // action to handle null JSON object.
            }               
            else
            {
                JSONArray jarray = data.getJSONArray("data");   
                int len=jarray.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
                {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jarray.get(i);

             String instanceName = obj.getString("instanceName");   
                        //extract data by whatever tag names you require, in this case instanceName.    
           } 
         }
} 
        catch (JSONException je)
        {
            je.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + je.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that jObj is being returned in doInBackground() but I am not
>   sure where it is being returned to.

The result of doinBackground() is received as a parameter in onPostExecute(). You are returning a json object in doinBackground() which is a parameter to onPostExecute().

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jObj) {
return;
}
```

Usage

```
new JSONParser().execute("url);
class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{

   //string parameter to doInBackground()
   //JSONObject - result returned in doInBackground() received as a param in onPostExecute()
}
```

You can also pass paramters to the constructor of your asynctask

```
 new JSONParser("url",params).execute();
```

In your asynctask;

```
String url;
List<NameValuePair> params;

// constructor
public JSONParser(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
this.url = url;
this.params = params;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  I'm still not sure how I would call this class using the the old parameters.  I try doing `JSONObject json = new JSONParser(loginURL, params).execute();` and it says that JSONParser's return type is not a JSONObject... isn't that what it is returning?

Comment: execute() doesn't return any value. Remember that the AsyncTask executes *asynchronously*, meaning that it will return at a later time and invoke `onPostExecute()`

Comment: but you return a value like string in doInbAckground() which is a parameter received in onPostExecute()

Comment: under the heading The 4 steps http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. the 4th point onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

from your `doInBackground` Method

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

 return jObj;
```

}

your return your `JsonObject` to

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jObj) {

    // Here you get your return JsonObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An Async Task has 3 attribures

```
Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.

Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.

Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
```

The point you need to understand is that you are creating a object of Async Task Class While calling `new JSONParser(loginURL, params);`

The solution is  that create a public result variable in your Async class and the call `execute()` on the object of class  and then access the public  object from the object.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now.  So would I declare a global JSONObject like `public static JSONObject jObj = null` then it could be accessed anywhere in my application?  Also, if another part of my application is expecting jObj to be not null, will Android know to to wait until the jObj has been set?

Comment: i wont recommend using a static variable in one class to be called in other class since in some condition android will recreate the activities or kill the background activities. It will be  better to parse your Json and Store  the details in persistent storage like dB or  manage your data in onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreSavedInstance.

Comment: I have a **UserFunctions** class which was originally intended to call `getJSONFromURL()` (in my original JSONParser class, at the top of my question) and store and work with its JSONObject return value.  I'm just trying to send the JSONObject that gets sent to `onPostExecute()` back to the **UserFunctions** class.  But from the answers here, I'm getting the impression that I need to move some of the UserFunctions functionality into `onPostExecute()`.  Is that what I have to do now that I'm using an AsyncTask?

Comment: best way is to save Values int Database and access it from any where you like, if you fell easy to move some of the UserFunctions functionality into onPostExecute() the go ahead with it.